# Model confidence set (MCS) in R

Tags: r

[image: MCS print out alpha = 0.3]

[image: MCS print out alpha = 0.6]
The above two screenshots are generated via the MCSprocedure function from the MCS package.  They only differ in alpha. The first takes alpha = 0.3, the second one alpha = 0.6.
Can somebody explain to me what the difference in Rank_M and Rank_R as well as v_M and v_R is? And also, what does the p value that is printed out refer to?

Comment: Hmm.  The online doc isn't helpful at all, is it?  I think you need to look at the [paper by Bernardi & Catania](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8504).  Section 4.3 seems relevant on a skim read.

Comment: @Limey Unfortunately both documents are not helpful regarding the column names. For the p value I think there's relevant clarification in Hansen(2011) - the original paper on the MCS.

Comment: @Limey In the paper  you mentioned at the top of page 5 there are two elimination rules, indexed with M and R. Do you think the ranking is based on those?